# List index out of bounds error SQL temporary table

Tags: sql

I am working on creating a temporary table in an SQL query wizard. How can i select a column (or columns) of data from a temporary table?

If i try to select one column from my temporary table I get a "List index out of bounds (1)" error. If i try to select two columns from my temporary table I get a 
"List index out of bounds (2)"

:::::::::::::::This query runs::::::::::::::

```
SELECT Arfile.PATIENT_NO Patient_no,
         Arfile.CHARGE_NO Charge_no,
         Arfile.CHARGE_SEQ Charge_seq,
         Arfile.ADJUST_TYPE Adjust_type,
         Arfile.AMOUNT Amount,
         Arfile.CHARGE_AMOUNT Charge_amount,
         Arfile.PAYMENT_AMOUNT Payment_amount,
         Arfile.ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT Adjustment_amount,
         Arfile.PAYMENT_TYPE Payment_type
INTO #testing1
    FROM dbo.ARFILE Arfile


Select *
from #testing1


drop table #testing1
```

::::::::::::::This Query gets an error::::::::

```
SELECT Arfile.PATIENT_NO Patient_no,
         Arfile.CHARGE_NO Charge_no,
         Arfile.CHARGE_SEQ Charge_seq,
         Arfile.ADJUST_TYPE Adjust_type,
         Arfile.AMOUNT Amount,
         Arfile.CHARGE_AMOUNT Charge_amount,
         Arfile.PAYMENT_AMOUNT Payment_amount,
         Arfile.ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT Adjustment_amount,
         Arfile.PAYMENT_TYPE Payment_type
INTO #testing1
    FROM dbo.ARFILE Arfile


Select Patient_no
from #testing1


drop table #testing1
```

Which DBMS are you using? 
The data is stored in SQL server and I'm using an SQL compiler called QS Reporter.

And what is the exact error message?
I've listed the exact error message previously in this post.

And what is this "SQL query wizard" thing?
QS Reporter.

::::This query gets an error::::

```
SELECT Arfile.PATIENT_NO

INTO #testing1
    FROM dbo.ARFILE

Select *
from #testing1

drop table #testing1
```

::::this query gets error "list index out of bounds (4)" ::::::

```
SELECT Arfile.PATIENT_NO Patient_no,
         Arfile.CHARGE_NO Charge_no,
         Arfile.CHARGE_SEQ Charge_seq,
         Arfile.ADJUST_TYPE Adjust_type
INTO #testing1
    FROM dbo.ARFILE Arfile


Select *
from #testing1


drop table #testing1
```

::::this query works::::

```
SELECT Arfile.PATIENT_NO Patient_no,
         Arfile.CHARGE_NO Charge_no,
         Arfile.CHARGE_SEQ Charge_seq,
         Arfile.ADJUST_TYPE Adjust_type,
         Arfile.AMOUNT Amount

INTO #testing1
    FROM dbo.ARFILE Arfile


Select *
from #testing1


drop table #testing1
```

Comment: Could you please add more details?  Knowing the database implementation being used would be helpful for determining the root cause of your issues.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And what is the **exact** error message? And what is this "SQL query wizard" thing?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you must use "AS" like Arfile.PATIENT_NO AS Patient_no and all others.

Comment: No. Using `AS` is optional